# What is the right way to share the digital assets to the will executor and eventually detect the person's death?

Tags: encryption, authentication, passwords

These days I brainstormed about how does one give their passwords/pin codes/etc to their will executor so that the executor can do what the person wanted after their death?

For instance, how would a person give them access to information like:

- my PayPal accounts (personal and business)
- Bitcoin Wallet
- maybe computer passwords
- phone PIN codes
- etc.

I am pretty sure writing them on a piece of paper is not the best idea, unless they are not somehow encrypted and can be decrypted by the executor.

From a security point of view, what would be the right way to verify the death of the person in an automatic way? Such as... if the person is offline/inactive on the internet for X days (e.g. 6 months, 1 year etc).

Is there a classical way to handle these credentials and internet data to the executor, making sure the executor will get access to them only after the person's death?

Comment: I seem to recall that there are legal services which can do this for you.

Comment: This is looking more like a legal question than an information security question, the way you've asked it. If you want to know how to protect the data *before* it is given to an executor, then that's a better fit here. There are lots of services to provide this information. And the legal process verifies the death of the person and then empowers the executor.

Comment: There's *some* room for a technical answer; services like https://www.deadmansswitch.net/ provide a digital "timeout" independent of any particular social-media or financial service - but cannot provide strong security assurances. A digital solution that could, and could support or augment a legal one, would be very useful. (That's how I interpreted the question, anyway)

Comment: @schroeder Yes, exactly. Regarding how does they validate the person's death, I was also asking from a security perspective: I was wondering if there is a way of setting a script somehow that will be executed if the person is _offline_ for more than 5 months, let's say... or something like that. Obviously, that isn't the best solution. I am wondering if something like that exists.

Comment: @IonicăBizău there are lots of ways to do that. Please edit your question to focus it a little.

Comment: What you want is to release the information upon your death, but not before, and you want to do it digitally. The traditional way is to write all that info down on paper and put it in a safe deposit box and give the key to a lawyer.

Comment: @schroeder I updated my question. Hopefully, it is a bit clearer.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Is there a reason that giving a lawyer a key card and having them use it in conjunction with deadman's switch services in the event of your legal death isn't enough?